# In a Play [2.4.x] environment is it possible to inject a variable name or a line into the routes file?

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.4

The line I'm referring to specifically is in the main routes file and refers to the module's routes file like so:

```
-> /somename mymodule.Routes
```

I would like to be able to change the value of `somename` via the application.conf configuration file (or elsewhere).

I have a sense this might be impossible and I might need to simply use a generic placeholder instead.

Comment: The mentioned routing will work, only if you mention main routes file in application.conf file. I have injected the route file with placeholders and it worked for me.

Comment: Yes I know this works - that is not the question I asked :)